# Align left-floating divs in the center

Tags: css, css-float

I have some left-floating divs. They need to freely wrap the as the window resizes. I need to center them horizontally.

```css
.el { background: green; width: 200px; height: 40px; 
      border: 1px solid; float: left; margin: 5px; text-align: center;}
.el:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
.el:nth-child(even) { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="el">1</div>
  <div class="el">2</div>
  <div class="el">3</div>
  <div class="el">4</div>
  <div class="el">5</div>
  <div class="el">6</div>
  <div class="el">7</div>
  <div class="el">8</div>
  <div class="el">9</div>
</div>
```

Codepen: 
http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/PGZQwp

Comment: A few options : 1.center the container --- 2. use inline-block instead ---- 3. use flexbox instead of float

Comment: just using inline block on .el does not work

Comment: Nop but it's the approach http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mALxOj for all 3 you need a little more

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Media queries for different screen resolution in order to wrap divs on browser resize. Use following CSS to make divs horizontally center. For ex:

```
.outer_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

where outer_container is css class name for out div which holds all child divs.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Main idea:

```
#container { text-align: center; }
.el { display: inline-block; }    

#container > * { text-align: initial; } /* resetting child align */
```

[Fixed CodePen sample](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/PGZQwp)

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you are trying to achieve this result.

```css
.el { background: green; width: 200px; height: 40px; 
      border: 1px solid; display:inline-block; margin: 5px; text-align: center;}
.el:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
.el:nth-child(even) { background: yellow; }
#container{margin:0px auto; width:100%; text-align:center}
body{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="el">1</div>
  <div class="el">2</div>
  <div class="el">3</div>
  <div class="el">4</div>
  <div class="el">5</div>
  <div class="el">6</div>
  <div class="el">7</div>
  <div class="el">8</div>
  <div class="el">9</div>
</div>
```